# Конвертация миллисекунд в дату

Tags: javascript, c#, дата, datetime

На клиенте получаю дату такого вида:

```
Sat May 05 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (зима))
```

Далее конвертирую эту дату в миллисекунды и передаю на сервер:

```
date.getTime() // return 1525467600000
```

На сервере конвертирую миллисекунды в дату, но тайм зона остается и дата смещается на 3 часа.

```
var tiks = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(long.Parse(milliseconds));
var date = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) + tiks //04.05.2018 21:00:00
```

Как правильно конвертировать миллисекунды, чтоб получить UTC дату без смещения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам необходимо либо конвертировать дату в UTC на клиенте, либо дополнительно передавать на сервер TimeZone.